# how can i check if i got the value from my ajax to my controller

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

This is the event that will trigger the login

```
$('#btnLogin').click(function(){
              //var data = $('#loginForm').serialize();

            var email = $('#loginEmail').val();
            var password = $('#loginPass').val();

            var result = '';

            if( email.trim() =='' ){
                //username.addClass('alert-danger');
                alert('email is required');
            }else{
                //username.removeClass('alert-danger');
                result +='1';
            }

            if( password.trim()==''){
                alert('password is required');
            }else if(password.length < 8){
                alert('password length must be atleast 8 characters');
            }else{
                //password.removeClass('alert-danger');
                result +='2';
            }

            /*var postData = {
            'email' : email,
            'password' : password
            };*/

            if (result=='12') {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '<?php echo site_url('login/identifying_usertype'); ?>',
                data: { email : email, password : password },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response){

                    //console.log(response);
                    //alert(email);
                    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                    },
                    error: function (XHR, status, error){
                        console.log('error', error);
                    }
                });
            }

        });
```

This is my controller:

```
public function identifying_usertype()
{
   if( $email = $this->input->post('email') )
    {
    echo json_encode( array('email' => $email) );
    }

    else
    {
    echo json_encode( array('error' => 'No email address') );
    }
}
```

Now im getting {"error":"No email address"} on my console there's no error. Is there something I'm missing? on my ajax i added dataType: 'json', i changed the url from base_url to site url

Comment: Is there any error in console ??

Comment: you dont need to put variable inside quotation, `echo $email;`. And in your success function uncomment `console.log(response);`

Comment: i removed the quotation mark i still get Undefined index: email

Comment: For testing purpose change everything to GET method and try it.

Comment: @JYoThI Testing purpose should be GET !!!! So POST will got error when release

Comment: do you mean $email = $_GET['email'];? if did try this one still the same error Undefined index

Comment: yes did you changed  this `type: "GET",`  ?

Comment: yes i did type: "GET", still the same error

Comment: Hit the url in browser `http://yourdomain.com/index.php/login/identifying_usertype?email=example@gmail.com`  check whether it's working or not .

Comment: this just a locahost xamp dont have domain

Comment: okay replace `yourdomain` with `localhost` and hit in browser and check .

Comment: You said you are getting udefined index error. Are you getting this error when you uncomment this line: `//alert(email);`

Comment: when your calling your ajax function . ? after clicking any button or page load ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have `success: function(response){`, the return value of the Ajax is on the variable `response` and not on `email`. So doing this will fix your issue:

```
success: function(response){
     email  = response;
     alert(email);
     //$('#myModal').modal('hide');
},
```

Answer (score 0):

1) The best way to create a link to one of your own controller/methods in CodeIgniter is to use site_url(), not base_url(). With site_url, your url becomes:

```
url: '<?php echo site_url('login/identifying_usertype'); ?>',
```

2) jQuery's $.ajax needs you to declare a dataType. Although if you leave it out jQuery will attempt to guess what it is, I've found it's wrong many times. Most people will use 'json':

```
dataType: 'json',
```

3) In your controller, if you are declaring that you want a json dataType, then it's really easy to send that back as the response:

```
echo json_encode( array('email' => $email) );
```

4) In your ajax success function, you can then do like this:

```
success: function( response ){
    if( response.email ){
        console.log(response.email);
    }else{
        console.log('email not verified');
    }
}
```

5) Lastly, you are not showing code that would create an event to execute your ajax. If you need help with that, let me know and I'll show you.

6) All of the network traffic is available for you to view in your browser's console. Check it, as it is very helpful when creating these ajax requests.

Regarding your comment, how about this in the controller:

```
public function identifying_usertype()
{
   if( $email = $this->input->post('email') )
   {
        echo json_encode( array('email' => $email) );
   }

   else
   {
        echo json_encode( array('error' => 'No email address') );
   }
}
```

Comment: this is what i get on my controller {"email":null} i check my console it says error SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1.

Comment: I updated my answer. If you're still getting an error, please update your question to show your current code.

Comment: I updated my question so you can check the code that i have and now i got this  on my controller {"error":"No email address"}

Comment: If you check the value of email in the console, right after the line var email = $('#loginEmail').val();, then is it what you think it should be?

Comment: I can't understand this if condition ```if( $email = $this->input->post('email') )```. It will always ```true```

Comment: No, it won't always be true, because if there is no email posted, $email becomes NULL or blank, and PHP considers that to evaluate to false. If that's not actually the case, then simply move it up and out of the if statement, and then check if( ! empty($email) )

Comment: What kind of error are you having now? Please be specific.

Comment: {"error":"No email address"} this is what i get on my controller. I still cant get the data i posted on my ajax

Comment: Replace controller contents with echo json_encode( $_POST ); and let me know what you get with console.log(response);

Comment: this what i get on my console {email: "lester@yahoo.com", password: "password"} lester@yahoo.com is the input i enter on the view

Comment: Now replace with echo json_encode( array('email' => $this->input->post('email') ) );

Comment: {"email":null} this is what i get

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152014/discussion-between-brian-gottier-and-lestah).